# Is there any overhead using this-> for accessing a member?

Tags: c++, performance, this

When accessing a member of some class, I can use e.g.:

```
this->myVar = 10
```

or I can just write:

```
myVar = 10
```

I like to use `this->` because it explicitly declares that the variable is a member of this class, but does it cause any overhead in comparison to just using the variable name by itself?

As an alternative I could maybe add a unique prefix to the vars, such as `_TmyVar`, but I've been using `this->` for a long time so I just wondered.

Comment: Consider a new coding style.  For example, if you name member variables like `myVar_` (with a trailing underbar), then there's no need to use `this->myVar_` to denote the fact that `myVar_` is a member.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no overhead. The compiler will generate the exact same code for both versions.

Answer (score 11):

Those two lines of code have the same meaning.  The `this->` is implicit in the second line.  They do exactly the same thing.

Thus, they perform exactly the same as well :-)

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference in meaning (unless there's more than one name `myVar` visible, in which case the ordinary version could mean a function-local variable while `this->myVar` means a member).  So yes, it's just a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

> I like to use this-> because it
>   explicitly declares that the variable
>   is a member of this class, but does it
>   occur any overhead in comparison to
>   just using the variable name by
>   itself?

Yes, it's more to write, and more to read, and indicates to readers of the code that it was written by someone not familiar with C++, so that they have to use extra time on carefully checking everything. All of that is programmers' overhead. It costs money.

There is, however, no overhead of the kind that generally doesn't cost anything, efficiency of generated machine code.

Summing up, there is overhead of the costly kind, and none of the cheap/free kind.

> As an alternative I could maybe add a
>   unique prefix to the vars, such as
>   _TmyVar, but I've been using this-> for a long time so I just wondered.

Names of the form `_TmyVar`, starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter, are reserved for the implementation.

Don't do that.

The two most common C++ naming conventions for non-static data members are `myVar` (prefix `my`) and `var_` (suffix `_`).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: An advantage of using this-> instead of a prefix is that your IDE might give you a nicer sorted list of the class members. Actually I do like the this-> prefix. There is no way to indicate better that it is a class member. But I would not do this for function calls.

Comment: @frast Don't adapt the code to rotten tools, programmers are much more important. See Charles Petzold's article ["Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?"](http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/DoesVisualStudioRotTheMind.html). Note: Charles Petzold = author of Microsoft's "Programming Windows", *the* classic book on Windows programming. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Nice article. I like the additional services of modern IDEs. They make me faster. There are so many APIs, I do not want to have to memorize all the identifiers. It is also easier on the eyes to leave out all this prefix and suffix stuff. Good Identifiers are always better IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I sometimes uses explicit this-> in setters, since they allow me to use the same name for the parameter names as the instance fields:

```
class MyClass 
{
    int foo;
    void setFoo(int foo) 
    {
        this->foo = foo;
    }
}
```

however, in constructors, I usually use initialization list, which does not require an explicit this->

```
class MyClass 
{
    int foo;
    MyClass(int foo) : 
        foo(foo) 
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about overhead of using `this->`. Working around name shadowing has nothing to do with that.